# Crash Free Users data incorrect

Tags: google-fabric

I have an application listed via Fabric. The stability alert email shows `Crash-Free Users has dropped to 66.4%.` for one day but if I observe the same in Fabric for that day, it shows a different value. How is this being calculated since it is making us think if the application is really causing the issue or the statistics being reported are incorrect? Image showing the Crash Free Users for that day below :

[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here, there are a couple of different reasons why this can happen, but we'll likely need to know more details. I'd recommend emailing support(at)fabric(dot)io.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.